# Need to compare the cell values of same column of a table based on another column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I need to compare the cells of a column of a table based on the value of another column value in sql.

```
 Id       A      B
 1       Ram     50
 2       Ram     50
 3       Siva    123
 4       Siva    25
 5       Rose    75
 6       Rose    75
 7       Siva    123
```

I have the above table, i need to check whether Ram in Column A has same value in column B, if not i should return false.

In the above case it should return false as Siva in(Column A) has different values in Column B.

I don't know how to do this. Kindly help on the same.

Result Expected

Return "False", as there is value mismatch for Siva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one trick

```
select A, 
       case when min(B)=max(B) then 'True' else 'False' end as Flag
From yourtable 
Group by A
```

or If you want to display the flag column for every row then

```
select A, 
       case when min(B)over(partition by A)=max(B)over(partition by A) then 'True' else 'False' end as Flag
From yourtable
```

**Update :** If you want to display `False` if at least one mismatch is present then

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM   yourtable
                     GROUP  BY A
                     HAVING Min(B) <> Max(B)) THEN 'False'
         ELSE 'True'
       END
```

Comment: Thanks :). I need to display a single message if there is a mismatch, my table may contain around 500 rows, so don't want to display for each row.Is it possible?

Comment: @Kumar - I don't get it. You just want to print `false` if at least one `A` is having `false` or what ?

Comment: Yeah, i just need compare whether the all values of B are having same value based on the value of A. In above case there is a mismatch for Siva rest are having same values .So i need to print false.